# EF 4 Code First - Problem while using inner query

Tags: frameworks, entity-framework-4, entity, code-first

I'm having problem using queries like this with Entity Framework 4 Code First:

```
var entities = context.TestEntities.Where( e => context.TestEntities2.Count() > 0)
```

The above query will generate the following exception:

> Unable to create a constant value of
>   type 'TestModel.TestEntities2'. Only
>   primitive types ('such as Int32,
>   String, and Guid') are supported in
>   this context.

The same code works if I use the model designer and generate the POCO-classes and thus using a ObjectContext instead.

EDIT: It works in a console-application but not while using my repository in an MVC 3 project.

EDIT 2: How about this:

```
var userProfile = ctx.UserProfiles.Where(p => p.User.Id == user.Id).SingleOrDefault();
return ctx.Feeds.Where( f => ctx.ProfileFollowers.Count() > 0 ).ToList();
```

The above two lines throws the exception. Commenting out the first line solves the problem. Bug in DbContext?

```
//var userProfile = ctx.UserProfiles.Where(p => p.User.Id == user.Id).SingleOrDefault();
return ctx.Feeds.Where( f => ctx.ProfileFollowers.Count() > 0 ).ToList();
```

Posted to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adonetefx/thread/2fb5ceea-9f30-4665-af98-945c6485f60b

Comment: What should this query do? The where extension doesn't contain any relation between entity and condition.

Comment: It should return all TestEntities if there are one or more TestEntities2 in the datastore (in this case MSSQL 2k8). TSSQL: 
SELECT * FROM testentities WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM testentities2) > 0

The real query is more complex, obviously, but this was the smallest test-case I could think of.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Any method:

```
var q = context.TestEntities.Where(a=>context.TestEntities2.Any());
```

This code results in the EXISTS clause:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ProductID] AS [ProductID], 
...
FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
1 AS [C1]
FROM [dbo].[Regions] AS [Extent2]
```

**UPD:** In case of repositories the correct way is to execute the first query and then the second one:

```
if(context.TestEntities2.Count() > 0)  
  var q = context.TestEntities.Select(t=>t);
```

Comment: The .Any() method trows the same exception. But it's more complex than that. It seems to be a bug in the DbContext (although I'm obviously not sure). It happens at random. Why would you split up the query if you use a repository? The repository uses the DbContext directly.

Comment: Everything depends on your architecture.